# Udp client python getting time

Tags: python, udp

how do I create a UDP client that prints out the time it took from the moment the message was sent to the moment the response from the server arrived.

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)

server_port = 21060
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
input_s = 'Hello, server!'
client_socket.sendto(bytes(input_s, encoding='utf8'), ('127.0.0.1', server_port))
input_s_modified, address = client_socket.recvfrom(65535)
print ('[CLIENT] Response from server {}, is: "{}"'.format(address, str(input_s_modified.decode('utf8'))))
client_socket.close()
```

this is my code which is absolutely nothing could someone help?

Comment: If the answer does not answer your question then please comment what you're looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the elapsed time between sending a UDP packet and receiving the response, get the system time before you send and immediately after getting the response, then print the elapsed time.

Note you should encode the data message to send BEFORE getting the start time and close the socket AFTER getting the stop time to better estimate the actual transit time.

```python
import socket
from time import time

server_port = 21060
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
input_s = 'Hello, server!'.encode('utf8')

sent_time = time() # time immediately before sending
client_socket.sendto(input_s, ('127.0.0.1', server_port))
input_s_modified, address = client_socket.recvfrom(65535)
recv_time = time() # time after received response

client_socket.close()

print('[CLIENT] Response from server {}, is: "{}"'.format(address, input_s_modified.decode('utf8')))
print("elapsed time =", recv_time - sent_time, 'seconds')
```

**Output:**

```
[CLIENT] Response from server ('127.0.0.1', 21060), is: "..."
elapsed time = 0.0010006427764892578 seconds
```